# Use same methods across multiple structs

Tags: go, struct, composition

I have a scenario where I have a few structs to model my database schema. What I want is to add a few methods to all those structs, so that I can use them in my handler. I achieved this using composition, but I have log utils in my parent struct, which is not getting initialized in child structs, because of which I am getting the following error

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Suppose my parent struct is something like following

```
    //Model is the top level model instance
    type Model struct {
        utils *utils.Util
    }
    
    // New creates an instance of model
    func New(utils *utils.Util) *Model {
        return &Model{utils: utils}
    }
    
    // Initialize creates/opens database
    func (m *Model) Initialize() bool {
        db, err := m.openConnection()
        if err != nil {
            return false
        }
        defer db.Close()
        ctx, cancelfunc := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
        defer cancelfunc()
        err = db.PingContext(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            m.utils.Log.Errorf("FAILED::could not ping database because of %s", err.Error())
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

My Child Struct looks something like following

```
// User act as model for database
type User struct {
    *Model
    FirstName    string `sql:"firstName"`
}
```

And in my handler method, I have the following

```
  user := new(model.User)
  err := user.Initialize()
```

Everything works fine as expected, but throws an error only when PingContext returns an error. The error that I get is following

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

This works fine when I call this method directly from the parent struct. Is there any better way to achieve what I want to achieve or am I doing something wrong. Please suggest.

I know in case when the method is called from child struct it is complaining that **m.utils** is not initialized because of which I am getting an error, but incase of parent struct it is initialized and I am not getting error.

Comment: There is no parent/child relationship between those structs, as you might have in traditional OOP languages.

Comment: I know that, I used the parent-child analogy to make things clear, what my question is. Thank you for pointing out though.

Comment: Using an analogy that clearly doesn't apply doesn't make things clear. It makes things unclear. But as long as you understand, that's the most important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You embedded a `*Model` in the user struct, which is initially nil. When you call `user.Initialize`, the initialize method is called with a nil receiver. You either have to initialize that model to point to a non-nil struct, or embed non-pointer. Since you also have to initialize the `Model`, you can do this:

```
type User struct {
    *Model
    FirstName    string `sql:"firstName"`
}
```

You have to initialize the Model and the utils in that model:

```
u:=new(model.User)
u.Model=model.New(utils)
u.Initilize()
```

Comment: I have created an instance of Parent struct under my main() method and If I called Model.Initialize(), It works. I also tried what you suggested, but still, I am getting the same error panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference.

Comment: Check the modified answer. Note that `model.New` is not a constructor, it will not be called automatically in any way. You have to initialize things one by one.